# How to parse a data using navigation in angular2

Tags: angular

Hi I am facing a problem on data parsing in angular-2 navigation. Lets describe first....

In menu.component.ts section I have a click event.. using click event I wanna pass two data (it may be api or static data)

template :

```
<p (click) = "clickData(link, id)">Click </p>
```

I would like to send this link into different component like.....

```
@Component {

   constructor(private route : Router){}

   clickData(link, id){
      this.route.navigation(["/text",id], link);
   }
}
```

till now it is working properly. Now I this navigation comes into a new component called "New.Component.ts"...

Here I want to get this link and id. For future progress.

Can you help me, how may I get this value....?

Answer (score 0):

In `New.Component.ts` just use the below code in OnInit function to extract the query param `id` (here + is to parse it as integer)

```
  constructor(private route : ActivatedRoute){}

  ngOnInit() { 
     this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => { 
     this.selectedId = +params['id']; 
     }); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

make following changes in your `New.Component.ts` file,  make sure your url params name should be `id` or change in code as you needed. working example [her on plnkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/smUy1twVS8v5YBdDa0c9/), look at `crisis-details.component.ts` under the crisis folder

```
constructor(private _routeParams: RouteParams) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let id = +this._routeParams.get('id'); // in my case param name is "id", 
                                          //use what ever you defined
    console.log(id);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

include modules,

```
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
```

inject in contructor

```
id: number;
constructor(private router: Router, private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute) {

}
```

find params in ngOnInit hook,

```
ngOnInit() {
             this.activeRoute.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
             this.id= +params['id'];
          }
```

now in this new component, use `this.id`

EDIT:

```
@RouteConfig([{path: '/component/:id/:link',name: 'MyCompB', component:MyCompB}])
```

pass  params like,

```
 this._router.navigate( ['MyCompB', {id: "someId", link: "your link"}]);
```

Comment: against the each click function I want to pass new dynamic value... I want to get the "link" not id....

Comment: Thanks. But You did not understand what I wanted to say. My concern is that, I would like to push a value from one component to another using router but not through url. Suppose I have two data. one is api and another is id. Id I will pass through url. but in child section I want this api. How may I do it...? Just like ionic 2 nav.push (). Same thing I want to Angular-2